# WooCommerce checkout goes blank when loading the site within an iframe

Tags: wordpress

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/iframe/" frameborder="0" style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;   height:100%;width:102%;position:absolute;top:120px;right:-16px;" height="120%" width="102%"></iframe>
```

WooCommerce checkout goes blank when loading the site within an iframe

[image: When view the cart show the then click process to checkout it shoe the blank page]

Comment: Can you have a screenshot of that? with more info.

Comment: Hi Mukesh i share the screen shot

Comment: I'm having the same issue if anyone does have an answer